# Drag and Drop of QListView Items

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt4.7, qlistview, qt4.8

Please help me out to solve this.... I have a `QListView` on the Left side and a `QWidget` on the other side. In `QListView` i had added few items using `QStandardItem`. Now i want to Drag and Drop the `QListView` Items to the other side `QWidget` and i have to do the same with the `QWidget` also. I can drag and drop my `QListView` Items *inside the `QListView`* itself by using

```
listView.setAcceptDrops(true);
listView.setDragEnabled(true);
listView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

this is working fine inside the QListView alone. I want to Drag and Drop the QListView Items to the other Widget. How can i do this? I know that i have to handle the Events like

```
void dropEvent(QDropEvent *);
void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *);
void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *);
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
```

i just tried it like this

```
void Example::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *e)
{
    // The event needs to be accepted here
    e->accept();
}

void Example::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    // Set the drop action to be the proposed action.
    e->acceptProposedAction();
}

void Example::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    qDebug("Items Dropped");
}
```

As i just tried with some **qDebug()** , *this is Working when i drag an Item from my `QListView` and Drop it in the `QWidget`*  and am getting the output as **"Items Dropped"**. *But i dont know how to bring my exact `QListView`'s Items* here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to subclass the view. All the drag and drop stuff is handled by the model, hence you have to subclass your standard model. You may want to take a look on the [model subclassing reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference). Of course you also have to change the drag-and-drop mode of your view to `QAbstractItemView::DragDrop` to get external drag and drop.